# Show a preview of the examples on the Markdown Editing Help page

Tags: feature-request, design

I honestly consider this and obviously an almost nonsense post, but I just noticed:
[image]
**Should those Styling/Headers Markdown Editing Help Examples Be an Actual Example?**
[image]
 
*I know they are intentionally created as non-actual example as the web developer 
have used a `<pre>` Preformatted Text tag*

Comment: Why shouldn't they be? The text demonstrates the actual Markdown syntax used.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the text was formatted, you wouldn't see the markdown, which would make the example useless. Are you suggesting that they put both the markdown and the "preview"?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Exactly what? Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you're suggesting.

Comment: So why *shouldn't* this be an actual example? What did you expect to see instead and how would a user discover what Markdown syntax to use for those stylings?

Answer (score 2):

I am getting your point, you're trying to say that the example of the code should be provided too. Such as:

> "*This is italicized*, and so is *this*." is result of: `*This is italicized*, and so is _this_.`

So that people who lack enough knowledge of English language (for example and most importantly ME), never knows what is meant by **italic**. I first thought this is something related to Italy or something like that, but then I came to know it means the Pisa; the Leaning tower! :-P

Your idea is a good one, but I think, it is better to add both the elements, one that would show the operator and other would give a real time example of the code being used. But using the `pre` tag is not of usage here. Just a simple example would do it for the newbie. And once you're a regular user, you won't even need the Help! :) You'll memorize it.

Comment: Yes thats why I know my question is really very minor design-need

Comment: Yes, but that's a need of the newbie! They need to understand what the site is and how can you format your post. You really need help, even I did...