# Question re-bumped by community every month

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-user, bump

This [question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5910/revisions), on the electronics meta site, gets bumped by Community about exactly the same day each and every month, and that's the seventh time (see the [timeline](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5910/revisions)).

Why? I haven't seen that for any other post. I thought there could be only one bump by Community per post. There doesn't seem to be a reason for that. It doesn't get edited otherwise, and it's pretty old now. And it's annoying, it's always on the top of the meta electronics main page, because of that.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting this, but [this answer from Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511) reads to me like that's acceptable. A bump is activity, so 30 days without activity... But I can't find anything to confirm how many times a post can be bumped.

Comment: @Kendra Indeed, it might be legit. But I go to this site from time to time, and it has been on the top of the front page almost constantly, which doesn't happen for the other questions also metting the required criterias. So it is strange... And, again, rather annoying.

Comment: So write an answer that gets upvotes? Or upvote one of the answers... community will bump it as long as it's got answers and they're sitting at 0.

Comment: @Catija. Good idea, indeed. I just threw upvotes, so we get rid of that. Thanks.

Comment: @dim If you just threw up votes, maybe you should see a doctor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Supporting Shadow's answer, as of last Sunday (prior to the upvote given), [that was the *only* question on Electronics Meta eligible for bumping](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.electronics/query/654193), according to [these rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511), which I [confirmed are still in effect](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/bump-rules), and assuming my query is correct ([it appears to be "close enough"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/bump-query)):

> [image]

Also the 30 day since last activity rule explains why you see it roughly monthly: The bump itself counts as activity.

So, yeah.

By comparison, SO has roughly 1.87 million eligible questions.

Comment: How many here? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Two, as of last sunday](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/654193). (My last query was broken, fixed now.) Although *now* neither one of those is eligible any more due to answer votes. Will have to wait until next Sunday to get a more up-to-date list.

Comment: @Sha most bumped question here: [11 times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/223804/revisions) ([query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/654198/most-community-bumped-posts))

Comment: @Cai Weirdly, according to that, 11 is the most bumps on *every* site I run it on. Huh... mysterious...

Comment: @Cai Oh it's because the `PostHistory` didn't include bumps until [a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279202/230261), so we can't  actually know if there were more than 11 bumps.

Comment: Ah yes of course

Comment: @Jason how come [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223804/show-a-preview-of-the-examples-on-the-markdown-editing-help-page) was not found by your script?

Comment: @Cai whoa... lol. Amazing how nobody is voting that answer! ;)

Comment: @Sha it was already bumped in the last 30 days, which excludes it from bumping (if you [remove the 30 days inactivity rule](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/654274) from that query you'll see a lot of posts that *will* be eligible for bumping)

Comment: @Cai oh wait.... "30 days with no activity" means no bumping either? In such case my answer is wrong. I thought I noticed same question bumped here more often than once in a month.

Comment: Yeh bumping included... that's why OPs question was bumped exactly every month

Answer (score 12):

Pretty sure there is no bug here.

The auto bump mechanism just picks questions at random. On smaller sites with less activity, the pool of "bump-able" questions is small, so the same question can be auto bumped over and over again.

As far as I know, the amount of times question was already bumped is not taken into account and does not affect the algorithm.